# Static source code analysis for C# that operates on source code level

Tags: c#, static-analysis

Current static source analysis tools for C# (or other .NET languages) usually operate on the assembly-level. They use reflection to analyse the code.

Are there tools available that operate on a source code level only (like lint for C)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) works at the code level and also [Microsoft StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis).

**SourceMonitor:**

> The freeware program SourceMonitor
>   lets you see inside your software
>   source code to find out how much code
>   you have and to identify the relative
>   complexity of your modules.

**StyleCop:**

> StyleCop analyzes C# source code to
>   enforce a set of style and consistency
>   rules. It can be run from inside of
>   Visual Studio or integrated into an
>   MSBuild project.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools (even R# does it), the right tool depends on the analysis you want to perform.

A dedicated tool that does it is [CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/products/codeit.right.aspx).
Another way is to use a parser (like the one [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) uses) and perform the analysis using your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into StyleCOP? It parses your source code and raises source-level issues. Otherwise, what's the issue with running on the IL?

Comment: We're looking into a solution to analyze source-code in a changeset *before* that changeset is added to a branch. This requires analysis on a source-code level, because there has been no build yet.

Personally I believe FxCop gives you more information, but FxCop cannot be used in the scenario I describe above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering commercial analyzers, I've evaluated [Klocwork Insight](http://www.klocwork.com/products/insight/), and it is clearly source based analysis for C#.

Answer (score 0):

My company provides  [Metrics analysis and code duplication analysis for C#](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/LanguageTools/CSharpTools.html), as well as a general tool for constructing arbitrary analysis and/or transformations, directly on C# source code.  The tools can operate on complete systems of files as well as individual files.